# Using df.itertuples() takes unusually long time

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I had 5 columns in a dataframe representing Year, month, day, hour, and minutes of each row. Using the following code I tried to add another column which uses the data in previous 5 columns to provide this format : YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

```
for row in df.itertuples():    
    df.loc[row[0],'date'] = datetime.datetime(int(row[1]),int(row[2]),int(row[3]),int(row[4]),int(row[-1]))
```

I must say I used dmap to convert coded minutes to show increments of 15 as below:

```
dmap = {263:0,264:15,265:30,266:45}
df['ALIAS'] = df['MEAS_TYPE_ELEMENT_ALIAS'].map(dmap)
```

The problem is it takes almost 1 hour for this code to work for 400,000 rows. I was wondering if anyone could help me to find a faster way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to know without sample data, but this seems to work just fine:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': ['2015', '2016', '2017'],
                   'Month': ['10', '11', '12'],
                   'Day': ['1', '2', '3'],
                   'Hour': ['10', '12', '14'],
                   'Minute': ['25', '35', '45'],
                   'Cat': list('ABC')})

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Hour', 'Minute']])
#  Cat Day Hour Minute Month  Year                Date
#0   A   1   10     25    10  2015 2015-10-01 10:25:00
#1   B   2   12     35    11  2016 2016-11-02 12:35:00
#2   C   3   14     45    12  2017 2017-12-03 14:45:00
```

If your columns are only `['Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Hour', 'Minute']` even this would work:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df)
```